# Insert new row to a QTableView by double-clicking the last row

Tags: c++, qt

Recently I was experimenting with `QTableViews` and I wanted to create something where I can add a new row to a table without having any additional button/menu item outside the table. I achieved this by adding a single item to the view's model and set that not editable. Then if a double-click happens on the table I check if it was on the last item. IF that is true I just add a new item before the last so my special item will be the last row every time.

Here is a minimal example which works:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTableView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTableView tableView;
    QStandardItemModel model{ 0, 1 };
    QStandardItem insertRow{ "<Click to add new item>" };
    insertRow.setEditable(false);

    tableView.setModel(&model);
    model.insertRow(0, &insertRow);

    QApplication::connect(&tableView, &QTableView::doubleClicked,
            [&model](const QModelIndex index)
    {
        int rowCount = model.rowCount();
        if (index.row() == rowCount - 1)
            model.insertRow(rowCount - 1, new QStandardItem{ "New item" });
    });

    tableView.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Is there a more proper way to implement this? Am I doing it right or this functionality is built into the Qt framework and I completely missed?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is a good one, but it has that non-editable last row hanging around. If you want to make the extra row editable, you can do as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628126/in-qt-create-a-table-with-an-blank-editable-row). The idiom of hitting a return in the current last row that produces an empty row, is a standard one.

I don't believe there is a built-in mechanism in Qt.

**A variation of the approach found [in the above link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628126/in-qt-create-a-table-with-an-blank-editable-row)**

In my app, I use a slightly different approach, and thought I would share it here. For convenience, I summarize both approaches here.

In the answer at the above link, both `MyTableModel` and `MyBlankRowModel` are derived from `QAbstractTableModel`, and the former is set as a `sourceModel` in the latter. This idiom implies that all `QAbstractTableModel` methods overridden in `MyTableModel` must be re-implemented in `MyBlankRowModel`, mostly forwarding to the `MyTableModel` methods, with exceptions as noted in that answer. This approach *can be cumbersome if a large number of `QAbstractTableModel` methods are overridden* in `MyTableModel` as is the case in my app.

Therefore I derive `MyBlankRowModel` from `MyTableModel`, only override a few methods: `rowCount()` returning `MyTableModel::rowCount() + 1`; `data(...)` and `setData(...)` to handle the row buffer. This offers the flexibility that `MyTableModel` can be designed to handle a complex model, and nothing in `MyBlankRowModel` has to change! It also simplifies the view interaction since I simply do `qTableView->setModel(myBlankRowModel)`.